# Bubble sort for letters

Tags: clojure, bubble-sort

I want to develop a bubble sort function that reorders letters into the correct order alphabetically.

So far this is my code

```
(defn bubble [ys x]
  (if-let [y (peek ys)]
    (if (> y x)
      (conj (pop ys) x y)
      (conj ys x))
    [x]))

(defn bubble-sort [xs]
  (let [ys (reduce bubble [] xs)]
    (if (= xs ys)
      xs
      (recur ys))))
```

I believe the issue is the > on the line `(if (> y x)` and the = on the line `(if (= xs ys)`. This makes it want a number and not a letter.

Is their anyway I can change this code to make it work for letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the comparisons more generically applicable using the [`compare`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/compare) function:

```
(defn bubble [ys x]
  (if-let [y (peek ys)]
    (if (neg? (compare x y))
      (conj (pop ys) x y)
      (conj ys x))
    [x]))

(defn bubble-sort [xs]
  (let [ys (reduce bubble [] xs)]
    (if (= xs ys)
      xs
      (recur ys))))

(bubble-sort [\b \a \c \z \h])
=> [\a \b \c \h \z]
```

You could also consider an optional argument allowing for custom comparators.

Comment: Thanks for the help